# Query string is broken when white space is added to parameter

Tags: c#, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I've got the following url:

`inspiratie/color-collections/test/test/S%200502-B/test`

And the rewrite rule within the `web.config`:

```
<rule name="color2">
  <match url="(kleur-en-inspiratie|inspiratie)/color-collections/([\S ^/]+)/([\S ^/]+)/([\S ^/]+)(/)?([\S ^/]*)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" logRewrittenUrl="true" appendQueryString="false" url="{R:1}/color-collections/color-detail?colorcollection={R:2}&amp;colorfamily={R:3}&amp;color={R:4}&amp;colorname={R:6}" />
</rule>
```

After the rule kicks in, the url becomes:

`inspiratie/color-collections?colorcollection=test&colorfamily=test&color=S&colorname=`

But the expected output would be:

`inspiratie/color-collections?colorcollection=test&colorfamily=test&color=S 0502-B&colorname=test`

As you can see if the space is used within the color code, the query string is broken after the color param (`{R:4}`).

When I test the rule within IIS, it works fine and returns the expected results.

I know that the unescaped white space will not work, but expecting the escaped one to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case problem cause because of encoding. You need to use `{UNENCODED_URL}` variable for regexp. Rule should be like that:

```
<rule name="color2">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{UNENCODED_URL}" pattern="(kleur-en-inspiratie|inspiratie)/color-collections/([\S ^/]+)/([\S ^/]+)/([\S ^/]+)(/)?([\S ^/]*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" logRewrittenUrl="true" appendQueryString="false" url="{C:1}/color-collections/color-detail?colorcollection={C:2}&amp;colorfamily={C:3}&amp;color={C:4}&amp;colorname={C:6}" />                    
</rule>
```

Comment: There are around 8000 colour variations. From what I understand, with your solution I would need to list all 8000 urls in `<add input="{UNENCODED_URL}"...`?

Comment: You don't need it. Why do you think so? It's kind of universal regexp which will rewrite `{VAR0}/color-collections/{VAR1}/{VAR2}/{VAR3}/{VAR4}` into `{VAR0}/color-collections?colorcollection={VAR1}&colorfamily={VAR2}&color={VAR3}&colorname={VAR4}`