# C# - Rest Call with trailing space in URI

Tags: c#, .net, rest, get

Before all: My client and service are both .NET Framework 4.5.2

I have the following service controller GET method:

```cs
[HttpGet, Route("GetObjects/{orderEntryId:int:min(1)}/{isBookFilterActive:bool}/{isOnlineFilterActive:bool}/{startIndex:int:min(0)}/{count:int:min(1)}/{*searchTerms?}")]
public List<ObjectSelectorResponse> GetObjects(int orderEntryId, bool isBookFilterActive, bool isOnlineFilterActive, int startIndex, int count, string searchTerms = "")
{
   // some code here
}
```

The calling Task in the client looks like

```cs
protected Task<T> Get<T>(int id, List<object> parameters, [CallerMemberName] string action = null)
{
    var encodedParameters = parameters.Select(p => Uri.EscapeDataString(p.ToString()));
    var requestUri = $"{CreatePath(action, id)}/{string.Join("/", encodedParameters)}";
    return SendRequest<T>(() => Client.GetAsync(requestUri));
}
```

When `parameters` is only a single whitespace character the `requestUri` looks like this as `Uri.EscapeDataString` turns a single space into `%20`

```
.../GetObjects/885901/True/False/0/30/%20
```

My problem is that i get the exception

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).'
```

The problem is NOT that the controller can't be reached at all because when i send a request like `<space>abc`

```
.../GetObjects/885901/True/False/0/30/%20abc
```

it jumps into `GetObjects` with the parameter `searchTerms` correctly filled as  `abc`.

So why is a single whitespace character causing these problems? And is there a way to fix that somehow?

## EDIT

I tested around ans also tried some other special characters and that is the result:

```
'%' turns to GetObjects/885901/True/False/0/30/%25
400 Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).'

'+' turns to GetObjects/885901/True/False/0/30/%2B
404 Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).'

' ' turns to GetObjects/885901/True/False/0/30/%20
404 Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).'
```

Its somehow strange that different characters lead to different exceptions?

Comment: you may try this solution.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47454851/query-string-is-broken-when-white-space-is-added-to-parameter

Comment: Try adding "trailing" slash, i.e. `var requestUri = $"{CreatePath(action, id)}/{string.Join("/", encodedParameters)}/";`

Comment: Sadly that doesnt do the trick either... result is the same

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's better for your case use **EscapeUriString** instead of **EscapeDataString** ? But be careful, in the following topic described potential risks of using this method.

[What's the difference between EscapeUriString and EscapeDataString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396598/whats-the-difference-between-escapeuristring-and-escapedatastring)

Comment: Unfortunately that turns a whitespace to `%20` too resulting in the same `.../GetObjects/885901/True/False/0/30/%20` query

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but have you tried to debug it with just empty space, not encoded? 
Probably you may try to add a check 

p.ToString() == " " ? p.ToString() : Uri.EscapeDataString(p.ToString()

Not sure if it's best solution, but at least you may give it a shot

Comment: Then the server controller receives an empty string and thats unfortunately also not what i want... i need the characters given by the client exactly like they are